# Python- How to convert stringed operator back to its special meaning?

Tags: python, string, operators

I am writing a program in python3.3 which requires me to evaluate a stringed expression like :

```
"2+3"
```

I converted the '2' and '3' to numbers using

```
int("2")
int("3")
```

But how do i change "+" to get its special meaning?

Comment: Try using an if statement. If string == "+" then a + b, or if "+" in string then do something

Comment: I have tried that one already but it involves a lot of indexes (in case of 2 digit or 3 digit numbers) which makes the program very long. I am looking for a way to make the program short.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are certain that the input of your program is coming from a safe source, then you can just [`eval`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#eval) your string, and you're done.

```
>>> eval('2+3')
5
```

If you can't use `eval` for whatever reason, try making a mapping of operator strings to their corresponding functions from the `operator` module:

```
>>> from operator import add, sub, mul, div
>>> opmap = {'+':add, '-':sub, '*':mul, '/':div}
>>> opmap.get('+')(int('2'), int('3'))
5
```

If you really can't do any of this, then one other way would be to use an if-elif statement with explicit evaluations like so:

```
if op == '+':
    int(left_operand) + int(right_operand)
elif op == '-':
    int(left_operand) - int(right_operand)
# etc.
```

Yet another way would be to play around with Python's special methods like `__add__` (maybe even `__radd__` if you want cross-type flexibility), and potentially use [`hasattr`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#hasattr) to see if a type supports an operation, but I would not recommend trying such an approach if you are a beginner to Python.

Comment: pretty exaustive ... just to be safe you could have put a method using pyparsing or ply :P

Comment: @JoranBeasley I had to *take out* one method. I made a mistake in thinking that `ast.literal_eval` would work. I tested it and it gives malformed string error for many operators. :\ I don't know what pyparsing and ply are. :)

Comment: lexxers/grammars https://erezsh.wordpress.com/2012/11/18/how-to-write-a-calculator-in-50-python-lines-without-eval/

Comment: @JoranBeasley Thanks, that looks interesting, I'll read it when I get some free time. :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`operrator`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html) module with an `if` statement :

```
>>> import operator
>>> a=3
>>> b=2
>>> s='+'
>>> if s=='+':
...  print operator.add(a,b)
... 
5
```

> The operator module exports a set of efficient functions corresponding to the intrinsic operators of Python.

Comment: This too would involve a whole lot of indexes because it is the user who will be giving the stringed expression. Isn't there a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: How is that different then if s === "+": print a + b. Same work, but without the import.

Comment: @msanti its not flexible as `operrator ` module also you can not use operators themself some wheres like in functions that just accept the functions as argument like `map` or ...

Comment: @RibhuDasPurkayastha Actually you can not do the parsing tasks easily! the most appropriate way for this task is using a proper parser!